# R, expanding M prefixes into 1000

Tags: r

one of the columns of my dataframe contains numerical values, some of which contaim "M" prefixes for 10^6 representation.

```
>col
...
[1177] "38141"  "39171"  "37019"  "38396"  "28390"  "29157"  "10876"  "28307"  "0"      "0"      "0"      "1.4 M" 
[1189] "0"      "0"      "1.5 M"  "36660"  "37650"  "94"     "89672"  "89898"  "34962"  "35907"  "40170"  "41255"
```

how can I expand them so I could make a full columns of numerical values?
initially i used strsplit and temp variables for storing those as a separate list

```
>spl_col<-strsplit(col, " ")
```

but then i end up with list some keys of which contain 2 values. no idea what to do next.
would appreciate any assistance

Comment: It seems these values are strings. How do you want the final output to be? As numerical or string?

Comment: yes, these are strings right now, I can't convert them accurately to numeric because of these prefixes. later on these have to be numerics

Comment: I removed the [tag:prefix] tag because your question is not about prefix, but rather suffix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace `M` (notice the space) with `e6` and coerce it to numeric.

```
> x <- c("3", "4", "1.5 M")
> as.numeric(gsub(pattern = " M", replacement = "e06", x = x))
[1]       3       4 1500000
```

Comment: awesome! just what i've been looking for! simple yet effective
`> bps[1188]
[1] "1.4 M"
> bps<-as.numeric(gsub(" M", "e06", bps))
> bps[1188]
[1] 1400000`

Answer (score 0):

using `gsub` uou can remove special characters:

```
as.numeric(gsub('M| +','',c("1.5 M","1.4 M")))
[1] 1.5 1.4
```